# Jenkins keeps on shutting down after every job run

Tags: linux, tomcat, jenkins, devops

No error logs, jenkins running on the tomcat instance is shutting down running on a linux machine. Restarting the tomcat instance gets it up and running but it shutdowns again after a job is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Type dmesg and check if there is any out of memory error. If the memory is too low, increase it. If it isn't validate if Jenkins version is stable and if it has appropriate java version.
Start Jenkins with parameter to create a heapdump on crash and run analyzer tool.